# iTextSharp XMLWorker does not work on css border-collapse: collapse;

Tags: itext

The HTML code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
                table tr td {
                    border: 2px solid black;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>row 1 cell 1</td>
                <td>row 1 cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2 cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2 cell 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

But in the output PDF file, the inner borders are doubled width.
I'm using the latest iTextSharp 5.5.6 & XML Worker 5.5.6.

Anyone has any idea why?

Thanks!
Leo

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the CSS function `border-collapse` isn't supported. As documented, XML Worker isn't an URL2PDF tool. It's a simple HTML2PDF tool that allows people to create simple templates in HTML to create reports in PDF. This means that you have support for plenty of HTML and CSS tags and attributes, but not all.

Comment: Well, their site clearly stated this CSS function is supported for both cell and table. Here is the link: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm
But, I did find a simple workaround to resolve this problem.

Comment: @user538220 Could you perhaps share this workaround with the rest of us? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-collapse: collapse;` appears to not actually collapse the borders, but just move them really close to each other, if you look carefully you can see a fine line in the middle of the fat border. I could only see it when my pdf is opened in Chrome, not in my pdf-reader.. Here is a screenshot showing what i mean:

[image: fine line in fat border]

So I ended up setting the top and left borders of the table, and the right and bottom borders of the cells in the table, which gave me the desired thin line of only 1px instead of 2px, (AKA: only one line, instead of two lines)

```
.tableborder {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-color: black;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
}

    .tableborder th, .tableborder td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-right-color: black;
        border-right-width: 1px;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-bottom-color: black;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
    }
```

Not pretty but it does the job ;-)

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

@[user538220](https://stackoverflow.com/users/538220/user538220), you mentioned a simple workaround in your comment, was it something like this, or was it a better solution?

Comment: I guess your solution works too. I would accept it as an answer. The workaround I mentioned is simple. Set the table border to 1 and both td,th borders to 0.5. It's not perfect but less CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

below code worked for me.

```
table th,td {
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-top-width: 0px;
}
```